# Do memory addresses have a different types from an integer type in ATT assembly language?

Tags: assembly, att

I know the ATT assembly language has integer types (word, double word, quad word), and floating point types (single precision, double precision).

Do memory addresses have an integer type, or its own type?

I saw that a memory address is specified directly while an integer constant is specified with a prefix `$`. Is that  because an integer and a memory address have different types?

Comment: They do.  In 32-bit code it is "double", in 64-bit code is "quad".  Just one more reason to dislike it.

Comment: On HW level no, it's just bare bit patterns stored at sequential memory addresses, each address containing 8 bits (one byte). That's the total information, which is stored in HW. The x86 CPU then understands how to access memory in bigger chunks (16b word, 32b dword, ...), fetching/writing multiple consecutive bytes, but the particular byte of memory doesn't know if it was written by a dword or byte instruction and in which position in the dword it was (and if it was 8 bit pattern as part of integer, or floating point value), all that is stripped down and only 8 bit pattern remains.

Comment: (some memory chips store some kind of consistency check bits ("ECC" system is one IIRC), which are then "extra" information with extra bits dedicated on chip to store those check values, but that should be pretty much transparent to programmer (except ones working on OS on the support for such memory check), from asm programmer point of view still only 8 bits per memory address are stored.)

Answer (score 1):

In AT&T syntax, different operands are indicated by different syntaxes:

```
%eax                register operand
(%eax)              indirect operand
foo                 direct operand
$foo                immediate operand
foo(%eax)           indexed operand
foo(%eax,%ebx,4)    scale, index, base operand
```

So the difference between `foo` and `$foo` is that the former refers to the memory at address `foo` whereas the latter refers to the address of `foo`.  As an example, the difference between

```
mov 0x1234, %eax
```

and

```
mov $0x1234, %eax
```

is that the former loads the value at address `0x1234` into `%eax` while the latter loads the value `0x1234`.

Comment: Thanks. What data types do an assembly language have? I know there are integer types (word, double word, quad word), and floating point types (single precision, double precision). Do memory addresses have an integer type, or its own type?

Comment: @Ben There is no single “assembly language” so your question cannot be answered in general.  Note further that objects do not have data types, they are just values somewhere in RAM.  When you instruct the CPU to operate on them, you tell the CPU how it should treat the data.  Memory addresses again are just numbers.  They are typically words, dwords, qwords, depending on whether you program in 16, 32, or 64 bit mode.  With segmentation, this is slightly different though.

Comment: @Ben: In asm, everything is just bytes.  It's up to the programmer to use instructions that do something useful.  e.g. normally you want to use `addsd` on XMM registers that hold bit patterns in IEEE754 double-precision floating point format.  But you can use integer increments on FP bit patterns to implement `nextafter`, and so on.  signed/unsigned integer is also totally up to the programmer based on which flags you check on x86, or which multiply instructions you use.